# how to check if the list is empty in a scala EitherT class

Tags: scala

i have the following code, which query DB and return value, the value is wrapped in a EitherT class,

```
 val result = emailModel.getStatusByEmail(emailAddress)

result type is : ProcessorResult[List[EmaiStatusDTO]] and 
type ProcessorResult[A] = ServiceResult[PermissionError, A] 
type ServiceResult[Err, A] = EitherT[Future, Err, A]
```

I need to check if the return from DB is empty, how do i do that? i tried this but obviously not working, i'm new to Scala, still try to figure it out...

```
if (result.collectRight().onComplete().isEmpty()) {
   return ProcessorResult(List(new EmaiStatusDTO(emailAddress, "Normal")))
} else {
   return result
}
```

Comment: `EitherT` here is from Cats, or what?

Comment: What do you want to do with the status in the end? What are possible statuses?

Comment: Looks like you have to unwrap result and check PermissionError first, then unwrap again and check ServiceResult's Err, and then unwrap a List[EmaiStatusDTO].

Comment: Check if this helps https://medium.com/@scalaisfun/optiont-and-eithert-in-scala-90241aba1bb7

Comment: @SethTisue: yes, EitherT is from Cats

Comment: @battlmonstr, updated my question, if the DB query return some record, i'll just return the result, otherwise I return a list of 'normal' EmailStatusDTO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you work with something like [EitherT from scalaz](https://scalaz.github.io/scalaz/scalaz-2.10-7.0.5/doc/index.html#scalaz.EitherT)

`getStatusByEmail` returns a "future" (a delayed computational task), which (if you run it) will return either a PermissionError, or a list - `List[EmaiStatusDTO]`.

Your intention is to change the empty list result to some fixed constant.

For this you could just use the EitherT.map function:

```
val result = emailModel.getStatusByEmail(emailAddress)
val defaultStatusList = List(new EmaiStatusDTO(emailAddress, "Normal")
return result.map(l => if (!l.isEmpty) l else defaultStatusList)
```